# Can someone explain me the meaning and process of passing hands upon fire then on the face?

Tags: rituals

I'm very new to hinduism, and I have seen this happening several times, but I cannot find any info about it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean after aarti?

Comment: Not very sure, because I have seen it on documentaries in general (where a flame is lit and people come and pass their hand over the fire and then touch their face or "swallow" the heat), but also in an amusement park a few days ago : the wheather was cold so the park has lit some some fires so visitors can heat up. At one of these fires stood an indian family and I saw the father pass his hand over the fire, and then gently rub his face.

Comment: If it is not related to arati done during Puja then I am afraid it has nothing to do with Hinduism.@jpicaude

Comment: And even if it's related to Arati then also  the correct way probably is to pass the hands over (or touch) the head rather than the face.

Comment: @rickross Many (or may be mostly) touches face instead of head (including me), may be coz of incorrect method we know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.

Comment: @Vishvam Yes I don't know why some touch the face .. may be the target the eyes .. but if we touch the head everything else is covered.